# jQuery validation + rails isn't firing

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm using

Rails: 5.1.4

Ruby: 2.4.1

I'm currently trying to get jQuery validation working with my rails app but I think the reason why it's not working is that when I inspect my code I'm getting an `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'addMethod' of undefined` error.

Now I have these gems installed:

**gem 'jquery-validation-rails'**

**gem 'jquery-rails'**

Here is my application.js file:

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require jquery.validate.additional-methods
//= require jquery.validate
//= require popper
//= require bootstrap-sprockets
//= require trix
//= require rails-ujs
//= require local-time
//= require turbolinks
//= require_tree .
```

Here is the validation jQuery I have so far:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 $(document).ready(function () {
 $("new-listing-form").validate(
 {
   rules: {
     listing_title: {
       required: true
     }
   }
 }
 );
 });
 </script>
```

I'm trying to test the validation on this form field:

```
<%= form.text_field :title, id: :listing_title, class: 'form-
 control', placeholder: 'What is the job title?' %>
```

What do you think is the matter with all of this?

Thank you ahead of time!

Comment: You have to give name of text field here `listing_title:`  . do inspect and check what is that exact name of text field.

Comment: Alright, I did have the wrong name but I'm still getting the `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'addMethod' of undefined` error when I inspect.

Comment: try to run simple this `$("new-listing-form").validate()` command in your browser's web console. May be you are creating your custom method in jquery validate

Comment: Okay, so that cleared up one of the errors. But it didn't fix the main error. Do you think that I installed jQuery wrong?

Comment: What you get when you run `$("new-listing-form").validate()` in your web console ?

Comment: I didn't get anything

Comment: Do you get any error in your web console , when you reload page ? do you know what is web console ?

Comment: Yes I get the same `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'addMethod' of undefined` as before

Answer (score 0):

1 - If you are using turbolinks then must use

```
$(document).on("turbolinks:load", function(){
  //the code
});
```

see turbolinks events
https://github.com/turbolinks/turbolinks

2- Like "new-listing-form" is not a tag

```
 $("new-listing-form")
```

never will find nothing